# The use of the word "close" in context

Tags: word-choice

Tell me please if the following use of the word is correct.

> His viewpoint is **close** to me, so I would rather side with him.

What I mean by that is that I like his viewpoint, and it is similar to mine. If that word is not used correctly, then what is the correct one to use there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would normally say “His viewpoint is close to **mine**.” Or “His viewpoint is close to my viewpoint.”

Close is a good word to imply that it is similar but not exactly the same. You could also use “similar” in place of “close”. I would view “similar” as a little more divergent than “close”, but not everyone will make the same distinction.